# Wildcard certs across two domains forms authentication via reverse proxy

Tags: ssl, single-sign-on, wildcard, forms-authentication, reverse-proxy

My company is facing a decision with regard to certificate renewals.  Presently, we have a UCC. We currently have two domains (under the same cert) and one of them is acting as a reverse proxy to the other.  It is said that at some point, SSO was working just fine in this scenario but I cannot confirm that as auth only occurs today under one of the domains.  My question is this... we are considering wildcard certs for the upcoming renewal (there are many other domains at play here).  Would switching to wildcard certs vs UCC change the complexity of the scenario that the developer said we had before with SSO?

Comment: Do the developers use their own code to validate certificates (hopefully not)? Or do they use a library which cannot deal with wildcards (hopefully not either)? If none of this is the case then it is transparent for the developer which kind of certificates are used.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly?  If neither of those are the case, we should not have to do any type of special configuration to allow SSL through one wildcard cert (of the destination domain) into the HTTPS access of another requesting domain via reverse-proxy?

Comment: Correct, there will be no difference for the developers just because you use wildcard instead of UCC.